# How can i get the displayed cell value in a JTable (not full TableModel value)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Normally, I get the value of a table cell in `JTable` using

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)
```

However, now I have a given input `JTable` (which I don't control or create) and need to get the **displayed** cell value as a `String`. If the value is a `Double`, it can have more digits than are displayed by the `JTable`.

Example: 
The `JTable` displays 0.37 (two digits) - but `getValueAt` returns 0.37234421

What I'm looking for is either get the **displayed value** as a `String`, or the # of digits displayed (so I can change the double from `getValueAt` accordingly()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force method would be

```
Object value = jtable.getValueAt(row, column);
Component component = jtable.getCellRenderer(row, column).getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
if (component instanceof JLabel) {
    String displayedValue = ((JLabel) component).getText(); // here you are
}
```

**Beware** the `CellRenderer` of a `JTable` can be replaced by someone by calling e.g. `jtable.setDefaultRenderer(columnClass, renderer)`. Then, depending on the implementation, the resulting `Component` might not be a `JLabel` any more. In the latter case a different logic is needed to retrieve the displayed value (i.e. cast `component` to different Class and retrieve it from that instance). **However** the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` implementation which is used by `JTable` by default returns a `JLabel`.

**BUT**
The value you see could be different from this as well .... if the column in the table is not wide enough in your table the text `23.4567` could be the text but the actually displayed text is `23.4...` ... If you want to know the factually displayed value a different approach is needed...

Comment: This seems to work very well, just tested it with some tables including some with table columns not displaying the number at all (shows "###") or showing a shortened number (shows "21.."). I would mark this as the answer, but you added the disclaimer that things can go very wrong. What could i do to make sure they don't (my testinput tables seem to work).

Comment: Thanks for this question, I elaborated on this in my answer in the **beware** and **however** section.